# What is the conductor of $ \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2 )/\mathbb Q?$ $4\mathbb Z$ or $8 \mathbb Z?$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

By execise 6.8 of Childress's *Class Field Theory*, $\mathbb f(\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)/ \mathbb Q)=8\mathbb Z$. But considering the norm of the local field about the place correspondent with 2, it should be $4\mathbb Z$ and there is contraction to the ordering theorem.

Comment: Certainly $m=8$ is the smallest integer such that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)\subseteq\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$. What does *the ording theorem* say. I couldn't find it.

Comment: Also, it seems to me that $1+8\Bbb{Z}$ is contained in the image of the norm map, but $1+4\Bbb{Z}$ certainly is not: $x^2-2y^2\not\equiv5\pmod8$. So [the local conductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor_(class_field_theory)#Local_conductor) is $3$ resulting in a factor $2^3$. What result suggests that it should $4$ only?

Comment: Yes, you are right. By the lemme 5.3 of Childress's Class Field Theory, I get that. And the ordering theorem is on P136. It seems that I am wrong about the image of the norm map.

Comment: I don't have Childress, that's why I asked you to quote the theorem. Anyway, integers congruent to $1$ modulo $8$ have square roots in $\Bbb{Q}_2$, so they are trivially included in the image of the norm.

Comment: Let $k_1/ \mathbb Q_p$ and $k_2/k_1$ be  finite extensions and $Gal(k_2/k_1)$ is cyclic. Let $\mathbb U_j$ denote the units of the valuation ring of $k_j$.Then $[\mathbb U_1 : \mathbb N_{k_2/k_1}\mathbb U_2]=e(k_2/k_1)$. In this case, $[1+2\mathbb Z_2:\mathbb N_{k_2/\mathbb Q_2}\mathbb U_2]=2$, then the image of the norm map is $1+2^2\mathbb Z_2$

Comment: @lorry $1+4\Bbb{Z}_2$ isn't the only subgroup of $1+2\Bbb{Z}_2$ of index $2$. In fact, one has $1+2\Bbb{Z}_2 =\{\pm 1\} \times 1+4\Bbb{Z}_2$, so another subgroup of index $2$ is $\{\pm 1\} \times 1+8\Bbb{Z}_2$

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen @ MatheinBoulomenos Thank you! It is because that $(\mathbb Z /8 \mathbb Z)^*$ is not cyclic and has two subgroups of index 2. It all makes sense.